# How do you vertically align an image to the middle of a div?

Tags: css, image, html

I am trying to put an image in a div and vertically align to the middle so it follows the previous div.
It goes like this

HTML

```
<div id="navigation">Navigation</div>
<div id="header"><img src="link"/></div>
<div id="content">content</div>
```

CSS

```
#header {
  height: 150px;
  width: 760px;
  background: red;
}
```

What line of code would I need in order to make this happen? Whenever I put the image, it stays in the bottom of the div. I want to raise the image so it goes to the top. There is no css code for aligning to the top. Just left and right.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use jQuery? if so try this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var headerHeight = $(".header").height();
        var imageHeight = $(".header img").height();
        $(".header img").css("margin-top",Math.floor((headerHeight - imageHeight) / 2));
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to use jQuery in order to vertically align image.

Answer (score 1):

Already answered here: [How to vertically align an image inside div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-div)

> use an inline-block helper with height: 100% and vertical-align:
>   middle on both elements.

```
display: inline-block;
height: 100%;
vertical-align:middle;
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/4RPFa/74/

Answer (score 0):

use the CSS of:

```
#header {
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
}
```